# How to fill  specific positional arguments with partial in python?

Tags: python

Basically, what I'd like to do is:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> partial(str.startswith, prefix='a')('a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: startswith() takes no keyword arguments
```

But more generally the question is, **how to fill specific positional arguments with `partial`**.

P.S. I do realize that I can use a `lambda` instead.

Comment: Go ahead and use `lambda`.  It will be a little slower because `partial` is implemented in C.  If performance is a premium you can implement your variant in C also.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It cannot be done.  You have to make a wrapper function.

Ostensibly, you would use keyword arguments, as you tried to do - that's what they're for, right?  Unfortunately, as you've discovered, python's standard library functions [do not take named parameters](http://muharem.wordpress.com/2006/12/01/first-experiments-with-pythons-functoolspartial/).  Thus, it is not possible given the current implementation of `partial` without making another function to run interference.

According to the acceptance of [PEP 309](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0309/), what was accepted for inclusion was "a partial() type constructor binding **leftmost** positional arguments and any keywords."  Furthermore, it states:

> Note that when the object is called as though it were a function, positional arguments are **appended** to those provided to the constructor, and keyword arguments override and augment those provided to the constructor.
>
> Positional arguments, keyword arguments or both can be supplied at when creating the object and when calling it.

Because additional positional arguments are *appended*, there would be no way to supply some preceding positional argument (by this implementation).

However, it goes on:

> Partially applying arguments from the **right**, or inserting arguments **at arbitrary positions** creates its own problems, but pending discovery of a good implementation and non-confusing semantics, I don't think it should be ruled out.

So, it apparently could be on the table, but as it stands, it is not implemented that way.

For the sake of disclosure, emphasis in quotes above was my own.

Answer (score 32):

I know this is old, but I run into this all the time, and I think I've created a neat solution. I use a slightly modified version of `partial` that uses an Ellipses object (`...`) as a placeholder value if you do not know it at the time that the object is built. It's quite useful for exactly this!

Here is the original `__call__` method of `partial`

```
def __call__(self, /, *args, **keywords):
    keywords = {**self.keywords, **keywords}
    return self.func(*self.args, *args, **keywords)
```

Instead, we can use the literal `...` as a special case to indicate a placeholder value

```
>>> type(...)
<class 'ellipsis'>
```

Here's the entire implementation:

```
class bind(partial):
    """
    An improved version of partial which accepts Ellipsis (...) as a placeholder
    """
    def __call__(self, *args, **keywords):
        keywords = {**self.keywords, **keywords}
        iargs = iter(args)
        args = (next(iargs) if arg is ... else arg for arg in self.args)
        return self.func(*args, *iargs, **keywords)
```

Usage is fairly straightforward

```
def foo(a, b, c, /, *, d):
    print(f"A({a}) B({b}) C({c}) D({d})")

f1 = bind(foo, 1, 2, 3, d=4)
f1()

f2 = bind(foo, 1, 2, d=4)
f2(3)

f3 = bind(foo, 1, ..., 3, d=4)
f3(2)

f4 = bind(foo, ..., 2, ..., d=4)
f4(1, 3)

f5 = bind(foo, ..., d=5)
f5(1, 2, 3, d=4)
```

Comment: Very clever idea with ellipsys, thank you!

Comment: You should propose this to the python-dev mailing list! Especially since PEP 309 indicates some openness to such proposals.

Comment: Very clever indeed, I second that you should suggest this on python-dev mailing list.

Comment: This is good enough and should be a package if it isn't

Comment: Linking back: https://discuss.python.org/t/functools-partial-extension-to-support-specific-positional-arguments/19163?u=wim

Comment: One small issue:  using `(next(iargs) if arg is ... else arg for arg in self.args)` prevents you from using `...` for two adjacent skipped args, doesn't it?

Answer (score 14):

If you really need this you can use [rpartial](http://funcy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/funcs.html#rpartial) from `funcy` 3rd-party library.

Its code is here:

```py
def rpartial(func, *args):
    return lambda *a: func(*(a + args))
```

So, your case can be handled as following:

```
>>> startswith_a = rpartial(str.startswith, 'a')
>>> startswith_a('abc')
True
>>> startswith_a('def')
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
# See: functoolspartial for binding...

class Function(object):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)

    def __add__(self, other):
        def subfn(*args, **kwargs):
            return self(*args, **kwargs) + other(*args, **kwargs)
        return subfn


class arg(object):
    """Tagging class"""
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index


class bind(Function):
    """Reorder positional arguments.
    Eg: g = f('yp', _1, 17, _0, dp=23)
    Then g('a', 'b', another=55) --> f('yp', 'b', 17, 'a', dp=23, another=55)
    """

    def __init__(self, fn, *pargs, **pkwargs):
        # Maximum index referred to by the user.
        # Inputs to f above this index will be passed through
        self.fn = fn
        self.pargs = pargs
        self.pkwargs = pkwargs
        self.max_gindex = max(
            (x.index if isinstance(x, arg) else -1 for x in pargs),
            default=-1)

    def __call__(self, *gargs, **gkwargs):
        fargs = \
            [gargs[x.index] if isinstance(x, arg) else x for x in self.pargs] + \
            list(gargs[self.max_gindex+1:])

        fkwargs = dict(self.pkwargs)
        fkwargs.update(gkwargs)    # Overwrite keys
        return self.fn(*fargs, *fkwargs)
```

Then try it out like:

```
def myfn(a,b,c):
print(a,b,c)

bind(myfn, arg(1), 17, arg(0))(19,14)
```

Answer (score 0):

My choice

```py
def upartial(f, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    An upgraded version of partial which accepts not named parameters
    """
    params = f.__code__.co_varnames[1:]
    kwargs = {**{param: arg for param, arg in zip(params, args)}, **kwargs}
    return partial(f, **kwargs)
```

try for your self

```py
def my_func(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

>>> upartial(my_func, "BB", c="CC")("AA")
'AABBCC'
```