# Make the function within pool.map to act on one specific argument of its multiple arguments

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing

In the following code, I want to multprocess `sum_` for three different values of `z` which are included in `np.array([1,2,3])`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
import numpy as np

def sum_(x, y, z):
    return x**1+y**2+z**3

sum_partial = partial(sum_, x = 1, y = 2)  # freeze x and y
a = np.array([1,2,3])  # three different values for z

p = Pool(4)
p.map(sum_partial, a)
```

`p.map(sum_partial, a)` gives the following error: `TypeError: sum_() got multiple values for keyword argument 'x'`, because for Python I reassign `a` to the kwarg `x` of my function. How can I make each variable of `np.array([1,2,3])` to fill the argument`z` of `sum_` instead of `x` so that I can get the following result:

```
[6, 13, 32]
```

which are respectively:

```
sum_partial(z=1), sum_partial(z=2), sum_partial(z=3)
```

?
I would like to keep using `pool.map`.

Btw is that possible to use multiprocessing both with an array of `y` and an array of `z` to finally get a list of `len(y)*len(z)` values?

Answer (score 0):

I find my answer [here](http://assorted-experience.blogspot.com/2013/09/python-multiprocessing-passing-multiple.html)

In my case it'll be:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def sum_(x, y, z):
    return x**1+y**2+z**3

def mf_wrap(args):
    return sum_(*args)

p = mp.Pool(4)

a = [1,2,3]
b = [0.1,0.2,0.3]
fl = [(1, i, j) for i in a for j in b]
#mf_wrap = lambda args: myfun(*args) -> this sucker, though more pythonic and compact, won't work

p.map(mf_wrap, fl)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811247/how-to-fill-specific-positional-arguments-with-partial-in-python) and [PEP309](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0309/), it appears that you cannot replace the first, leftmost argument of a function with `partial`.
Hence, you should slightly modify your code such that your iterable `z` is the first argument:

```
def sum_(z, x, y):
    return x**1+y**2+z**3
```

This works for me and yields the desired result.

**Edit**:
Regarding your second questions, you could use itertools to generate the arguments:

```
import itertools
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [7, 8, 9]
c = list(itertools.product(a, b))
print c

Out[74]: [(1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9)]
```

In that case, your `sum_` should expect a tuple as input:

```
def sum_(values, z):
    x, y = values
    return x**1+y**2+z**3

sum_partial = partial(sum_, z=2)
map(sum_partial, c)

Out[88]: [58, 73, 90, 59, 74, 91, 60, 75, 92]
```