# Map dict lookup

Tags: python

I have a function for getting an item from a dict:

```py
def dict_lookup(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary[key]
```

I'll be mapping this function via multiprocessing to look up values from a series of *very* long dicts:

```py
dictlist = [{}, {}, {}]
dict_lookup_partial = functools.partial(dict_lookup, key=some_key)
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    values = pool.map(dict_lookup_partial, dictlist)
```

I feel like I shouldn't have to define a function for getting a value from a dict. Is there some inbuilt way to do this?

Comment: This "function for getting an item from a dict" is called [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) function from the standard library's [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module provides this behaviour:

```
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> import operator
>>> dictlist = [{'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c': 10}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 20},
                {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 30}]
>>> agetter = operator.itemgetter('a')
>>> with mp.Pool() as pool:
...     avalues = pool.map(agetter, dictlist)
... 
>>> avalues
[1, 3, 5]
```

It can also be used to retrieve values for multiple keys:

```
>>> bcgetter = operator.itemgetter('b', 'c')
>>> with mp.Pool() as pool:
...     bcvalues = pool.map(bcgetter, dictlist)
... 
>>> bcvalues
[(2, 10), (4, 20), (6, 30)]
```

In general, the operator module is the first place to look for a function that replicates a builtin's behaviour for use in `map`, `filter` or `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

There is `dict.__getitem__` function. It's called everytime you access the dictionary value through square brackets like this: `dictionary[key]`, but you can call it explicitly.

```py
>>> d = {"foo": "bar"}
>>> dict.__getitem__(d, "foo")
"bar"
```

Comment: Nice! Sadly it looks like `functools.partial` can't handle filling in the 2nd positional parameter of builtins - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811247/how-to-fill-specific-positional-arguments-with-partial-in-python - so I'd need a wrapper function anyway,